# Appending text to end of line with sed - shell script

Tags: bash, sed, debian

I've got a simple shell script that I almost have working as desired.

## Requirements:

- Read file names in dir into an array
- iterate through the files and append text to the end of a matching line

So far req one is achieved however, I cannot seem to get sed to append properly to a line.

For example here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
FILES=(/etc/openvpn/TorGuard.*)
TMPFILES=()

if [[ ${#FILES[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "####### Files Found #######"
    for file in "${FILES[@]}"; do
        echo "Modifying $file.."
        line=$(grep -n "auth-user-pass" "$file" | cut -d: -f -1)
        array=($(sed -e $line's/$/ creds.txt &/' "$file"))
        tmp="${file/.conf/.ovpn}"
        echo "$tmp created.."
        TMPFILES+=("$tmp")
        printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" > ${tmp}
    done
fi
```

Expected output:

```
....
....
auth-user-pass creds.txt
...
...
```

Received output:

```
...
...
auth-user-pass
creds.txt
...
...
```

Comment: The newline is inserted by `printf`. The `&` in your `sed` should only be used when a matched string is recalled. The `$` (End-of-line) doesn't disappear.

Comment: So really, your question is why doesn't `echo "auth-user-pass" | sed 's/$/ creds.txt &/' "$file`  work ;-)? The `-e` is almost always superfluous. Speaking of superflous, capturing `$line` (lineNum?) what happens to your script if there are 2 or more lines that match? You don't need that  processing at all. If you want all lines to process use `sed` cmd as I first indicated, if you want only the first occurance fixed, then `sed /....../q` (q for quit) will do what you need.,  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` can be difficult with special characters. In this case you might use `&`, what will be replaced by he completed matched string.

```
for file in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    echo "Modifying ${file}.."
    sed -i 's/.*auth-user-pass.*/& creds.txt/' "${file}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by changing the sed flag from -e > -i and removed the use of tmp files and do it with sed:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
FILES=(/etc/openvpn/TorGuard.*)

if [[ ${#FILES[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "####### Files Found #######"
    for file in "${FILES[@]}"; do
        echo "Modifying $file.."
        line=$(grep -n "auth-user-pass" "$file" | cut -d: -f -1)
        sed -i $line's/$/ creds.txt &/' "$file"
    done
fi
```

Comment: your `grep | cut; sed`, etc. is equivalent to just `sed '/auth-user-pass/ s/$/ creds.txt /'` or [@WalterA's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56915626/1745001).